# Linux Shell Script Files and Directory Loop

Tags: linux, shell, loops, directory

I want to write a shell script in Linux that loops through all directory and sub-directories and cat all text files once. below is what i got so far, im a little behind logic on this one. can someone give me a hand? thanks

the script take 1 argument 
eg: ./script.sh directoryName

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Directory $1"

cd $1
for f in *.txt
do
cat $f
done
```

im unsure how to go into sub directories from here, as there can be infinite amount in each sub-directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find`.

If your operating system supports a modern version of POSIX:

```
find "$1" -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat '{}' +
```

...or, if it doesn't:

```
find "$1" -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat '{}' ';'
```

...or, if you want to be inefficient (or have a more interesting use case you haven't told us about), and your `find` supports `-print0`...

```
find "$1" -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | \
  while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
    cat "$filename"
  done
```

Don't leave out the `-print0` -- otherwise, maliciously-named files (with newlines in their names) can inject arbitrary names into your stream (at worst), or hide from processing (at best).

Comment: @NewFile, `-print0` NUL-delimits names, rather than newline-delimiting.

Comment: The folder name?find $1 -type -f -name '*.txt' -exec cat '{}' +

Comment: @JimBlack `"$1"`, not unquoted `$1`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How `'{}' ';'` or `'{}' +` different from traditional `{} \;` used in `find`?

Comment: @Bill `';'` processes one item per invocation; `+` processes as many as possible, like xargs. `'{}'` differs from bare `{}` only inasmuch as it's compatible with zsh as well as POSIX shells.

Answer (score 2):

You could either use `find` or recursion.

Example using recursion:

```
dump_files()
{
   for f in $1/*; do
       if [[ -f $f ]]; then
           cat $f
       elif [[ -d $f ]]; then
           dump_files $f
       fi
   done
}
```

Comment: i did exactly what you write but i got syntax error around the line fi

Comment: Yeah what I had written included a syntax error but @JohnKugelman fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

If you want a particular directory, replace the `.` with the full path of the directory. `find` gets the files that ends with extension `.txt` and pipes it to `xargs` that runs the command `cat` on them. `-0` option `xargs` takes the input literally. `-print0` mode is suitable for this...

Comment: If you have a modern enough find to have `-print0`, why not use the `-exec {} +` form (which, like xargs, also puts as many arguments onto each `cat` command line as possible)?

Comment: Don't disagree with you, @CharlesDuffy. I was putting a different option, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

change loop with

```
for f in $(find . -name *.txt);do
   cat $f
done
```

Comment: -1; this is actively harmful / creates bugs. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 (in addition to the lack of quoting on expansion)

Comment: Untrue. `for f in *.txt` is safe. Read the linked page.